# sqlite query unsorted result

Tags: sql, linux, database, sqlite

I have list of Ids `31165,31160,31321,31322,31199,31136` which is dynamic.

When I run query

```
select id,name from master_movievod where id in(31165,31160,31321,31322,31199,31136);
```

I get following result

```
31136|Independence Day
31160|Planet of the Apes
31165|Mrs. Doubtfire
31199|Moulin Rouge
31321|Adult Movie 2
31322|Adult Movie 3
```

This is sorted list in ascending order.

I want the list in the same order which I give as input like

```
31165|Mrs. Doubtfire
31160|Planet of the Apes
31321|Adult Movie 2
31322|Adult Movie 3
31199|Moulin Rouge
31136|Independece Day
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without an `order by` clause, there's no guarantee on the order a database returns the results to you. SQLite, unfortunately, doesn't have something like MySQL's `field` for custom sorting, but you can jimmy-rig something with a `case` expression:

```
SELECT   id, name
FROM     master_movievod 
WHERE    id IN (31165, 31160, 31321, 31322, 31199, 31136)
ORDER BY CASE ID WHEN 31165 THEN 0
                 WHEN 31160 THEN 1
                 WHEN 31321 THEN 2
                 WHEN 31322 THEN 3
                 WHEN 31199 THEN 4
                 WHEN 31136 THEN 5
          END ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, SQLite does not have an option like MySQL's `FIELD` for doing a custom ordering.  You are left with two options.  The first is that you could create a custom table containing the ordering you want and use that to sort.  This option isn't very attractive.  The second (and easier) option is to use `ORDER BY CASE` to achieve the order you want:

```
SELECT id, name FROM master_movievod
WHERE id IN (31165,31160,31321,31322,31199,31136)
ORDER BY 
    CASE id
        WHEN 31165 THEN 0
        WHEN 31160 THEN 1
        WHEN 31321 THEN 2
        WHEN 31322 THEN 3
        WHEN 31199 THEN 4
        WHEN 31136 THEN 5
    END ASC
```